# Onde colocar a string de conexão com o banco de dados?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Tenho o formulário:

[image: formulario Cadastro]

Já foi criado o banco e a tabela para cadastro, estou usando o wampserver e o MySQL Workbench.

Minha dúvida é onde colocar a string de conexão:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Server=localhost;Database=banco_teste;uid=root;pwd=;");
```

Atualmente meu código está assim:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace teste_DB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Server=localhost;Database=banco_teste;uid=root;pwd=;");
        }

        private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Quando tento abrir a conexão dentro do método `btnGravar_Click`:

```
private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

O Visual Studio me retorna erro informando que o nome `conn` não existe no contexto.

Onde eu posso declarar a string de conexão para que eu possa abrir a conexão sempre que eu queira?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A configuração de conexão pode ser colocado no arquivo App.Config, na connectionStrings com o nome de MysqlConnection.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>    
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="MysqlConnection" 
         connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=testdb;Uid=root;Pwd=senha;" 
         providerName="Mysql.Data.MysqlClient"/>  
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Para utilizar essa configuração pode ser feito assim:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnection"].ConnectionString);
```

A variável `conn` para ser acessada nessa classe deve ser criada fora do construtor, como exemplo abaixo:

```
namespace teste_DB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MySqlConnection conn = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //ta assim  
            //conn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info=False;Server=localhost;Database=banco_teste;uid=root;pwd=;");
           //pode ficar assim com a connectionStrings do App.config
           conn = new MysqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MysqlConnection"].ConnectionString);
        }

        private void btnGravar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

***Obs:*** *Um dica que eu dou como é uma linguagem Orientada a Objeto, transportar isso para um modelo melhor com Dal e BLL do que ficar abrindo isso todas as vezes que tem um novo formulário.*